Swift AVCaptureSession - Bounding Box Offset Issue and Video Orientation Best Practices
I’m working on an iOS app that uses AVCaptureSession to capture a live video feed from the back camera. My goal is to detect animals using a VNRecognizeAnimalsRequest and display bounding boxes around recognized objects.
However, I’m encountering a few issues and have questions on best practices:
Code Overview
Here’s the relevant code for setting up the camera feed and displaying bounding boxes around detected objects:
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision

class VideoFeedViewController2: UIViewController {
    private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    
    private lazy var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    
    private var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    private var captureDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    private var boundingBoxLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
        
        addCameraInput()
        showCameraFeed()
        getCameraFrames()
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        updatePreviewLayerOrientation()
    }
    
    private func updatePreviewLayerOrientation() {
        let currentOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        
        switch currentOrientation {
        case .portrait:
            previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        case .landscapeLeft:
            previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
        case .landscapeRight:
            previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    private func addCameraInput() {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
            deviceTypes: [.builtInTrueDepthCamera, .builtInDualCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera],
            mediaType: .video,
            position: .back
        ).devices.first else { fatalError("No camera") }
        
        self.captureDevice = device
        
        let cameraInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
    }
    
    private func showCameraFeed() {
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        
        previewLayer.frame = view.frame
    }
    
    private func getCameraFrames() {
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "camera-test"))
        
        captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
        
        guard let captureConnection = videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video) else {
            fatalError("No video connection found!")
        }
        captureConnection.isEnabled = true
        captureConnection.isCameraIntrinsicMatrixDeliveryEnabled = true
    }
    
    private func detectBoundingBox(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, _ cmSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
        let detectionRequest = VNRecognizeAnimalsRequest(completionHandler: detectionCompletionHandler)
        
        let imageResultHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: .down, options: [:])
        try? imageResultHandler.perform([detectionRequest])
        
        func detectionCompletionHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.clearDrawings()
                
                guard
                    let results = request.results,
                    let observation = results.first as? VNRecognizedObjectObservation
                else {
                    if let captureDevice = self.captureDevice {
                        try? captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
                        captureDevice.ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: 1.0, withRate: 2.0)
                        captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
                    }
                    return
                }
                
                if observation.confidence > 0.5 {
                    self.handleObservation(observation, pixelBuffer, cmSampleBuffer)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func handleObservation(_ observation: VNRecognizedObjectObservation, _ pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, _ cmSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
        let boundingBox = observation.boundingBox
        
        let size = createBoundingBoxShape(boundingBox)
        
        func createBoundingBoxShape(_ boundingBox: CGRect) -> CGFloat {
            let width = previewLayer.bounds.width
            let height = previewLayer.bounds.height
            
            let adjustedBoundingBox = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 1 - boundingBox.origin.x, y: boundingBox.origin.y), size: boundingBox.size)
            let boundingBoxOnScreen = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(adjustedBoundingBox, Int(width), Int(height))
            
            let boundingBoxShape = CAShapeLayer()
            
            let boundingBoxPath = CGPath(rect: boundingBoxOnScreen, transform: nil)
            boundingBoxShape.path = boundingBoxPath
            
            boundingBoxShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            boundingBoxShape.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            
            let boundingBoxWidth = boundingBoxOnScreen.width
            let boundingBoxHeight = boundingBoxOnScreen.height
            let boundingBoxArea = boundingBoxWidth * boundingBoxHeight
            
            let imageWidth = previewLayer.bounds.width
            let imageHeight = previewLayer.bounds.height
            let imageArea = imageWidth * imageHeight
            
            let boundingBoxPercentage = (boundingBoxArea / imageArea) * 100
            
            let textLayer = CATextLayer()
            textLayer.string = String(format: "%.2f%%", boundingBoxPercentage)
            textLayer.fontSize = 24
            textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: boundingBoxOnScreen.origin.x, y: boundingBoxOnScreen.origin.y - 20, width: 50, height: 20)
            
            boundingBoxShape.addSublayer(textLayer)
            
            view.layer.addSublayer(boundingBoxShape)
            boundingBoxLayer = boundingBoxShape
            
            return boundingBoxPercentage
        }
    }
    
    private func clearDrawings() {
        boundingBoxLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}

extension VideoFeedViewController2: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let frame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            debugPrint("No image")
            return
        }
        
        detectBoundingBox(pixelBuffer: frame, sampleBuffer)
    }
}

My Questions

Best Practices for AVCaptureSession Setup:
•   Are there any best practices or recommended settings to consider when working with AVCaptureSession to ensure smooth video feed and accurate frame handling?

Bounding Box Offset Issue:
•   The bounding boxes around detected objects are positioned correctly in the Y-axis but are offset on the X-axis (shifted to the right). I’m calculating the bounding box using the VNImageRectForNormalizedRect method. Is there a standard way to handle this offset?

Video Orientation Handling:
•   I would like the app to work in both portrait and landscape modes, with landscapeLeft as the primary orientation (iPhone in landscape with the back camera on the left side). However, the app should adapt to portrait mode as well. What is the recommended approach for handling videoOrientation with AVCaptureSession to ensure the orientation matches device rotation?


Thank you in advance for any insights or advice on these issues!
